# Slicing N rows from Pandas Multi-Index Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, series

Through this:

```
series = dataframe.groupby(['Index_1', 'Index_2']).size()
series = series.sort_values(0, ascending=False)
series = series.sort_index(level='Index_1', sort_remaining=False)
```

I'll obtain the following, which is a sorted Series with a Multi-Index.

```
Index_1  Index_2
111      0860    510
         0890    375
         1150    225
         0810    164
                 ...
2535     0454      1
         0325      1
         0266      1
         0470      1
                 ...
```

Now what I would like to achieve is to filter the top N rows preserving both indexes and series sorting. Like this, say Top 2:

```
Index_1  Index_2
111      0860    510
         0890    375
2535     0454      1
         0325      1
```

Any advice?

Comment: `series.groupby(level=0).head(2)`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @ALollz. It did the trick.